# Scrape table from web and display it in gui

Tags: python, html, scripting, web-scraping, scrapy

i would like to scrape a table from a website and display the scraped table afterwards in a gui created with python. The table (and the website) is in html. How would you make it? In case that is possible i would love to display the table in my gui afterwards formatted in the exact same way. "Hypothetical it would be enough for me to take a screenshot of the table and display this picture afterwards in the gui"

Ps: i thought using scrapy but i guess in that case i have to build the table from scratch again in my gui later?

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need `scrapy` if you just need to scrape a single page and don't need crawling. As for the toolkit [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) + [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is a popular choice.

As for the table content - you will most likely store in a list of lists (maybe some structure - it's up to you) and than populate table in your GUI application.

Comment: thanks for the advice! any idea how i can handle the formatting issue? the thing is that the table contains many numbers with color coding.

Comment: Maybe the easier way would be just to have an HTML component in your GUI app and make it render the html you'll grab from the said web page?

Comment: Is there some way i could make a "screenshot" in an automated way from a table of a website that is open in my browser? That would make the whole thing a lot simpler

Comment: You can try something like https://github.com/coderholic/PyWebShot or http://grabz.it/api/python/ (or any other lib, there are plenty of them). However most of them (if not all of them) make screenshots of the entire page. So you will have to figure out how to crop it down to your table.